# Each undeclared identifier is reported only once?

Tags: c, process, pipe

I am writing a c program involving communication between child and parent by directional pipe

Here is part of my code:

```
 char writemsg[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Sugar Lover"; 
  char readmsg[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char parrecieve[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char childrecieve[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
  int fd[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t pid;

  if (pipe(fd) == -1|| pipe(fd2) == -1) {
    printf("Pipe failed");
    return 1;
  }
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */
    printf( "Fork Failed");
    return 1;
  }

  if (pid > 0) { /* parent process */
    int i =0;
    close(fd[READ_END]);/* close the unused end of the pipe */
    while(writemsg[i] !='\0'){
      write(fd[WRITE_END],&writemsg[i] , sizeof(char)); 
      i++;
    }
    close(fd[WRITE_END]);
    i = 0;
    close(fd2[WRTIE_END]);
    while(read(fd2[READ_END], &parrecieve[i], sizeof(char))!=0){
      printf("%c", parrecieve[i]);
      i++;

    }

    close(fd2[READ_END]);


  }
```

It's complaining about this line when compiling:

```
 close(fd2[WRTIE_END]);
```

Could anybody tell me why?Thanks!

Comment: Descriptive titles FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename `WRTIE_END` to `WRITE_END`.

Read error messages more carefully and try to understand them.

Comment: Yea.. was programing for hours and now too tired to find typo by myself :( Thanks tho!

Comment: @NobWong: it happens :) more experience you have, more obvious some things become :)